Bearer token not working with [Authorize] as @attribute
I cannot figure how to use @attribute [Authorize] in razor component with Bearer token authentication. When I decorate API controller with [Authorize] and attach bearer token to header, its working nicely. When I use same attribute in razor component it always throw 401.
I tried using multiple schemas with fallbacks
@attribute [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Identity.BearerAndApplication, Identity.Bearer, Identity.Application, Identity.External")]

but did not help. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Are you using SSR? The bearer authentication will only work with SSR.

I tried to [Authorize] page on server side as well but still the same 401 response.

These schemes is for http requests. When you use [Authorize(...)] in blazor, this attribute will go to IAuthorizationHandler twice.
Firstly, it check if the HttpContext meet the requirement. (In your scenario, it check if the HttpContext.Request.Header has the correct token).
Second, if you have AuthorizeRouteView in Routes.razor. It will check if the user identity from AuthenticationStateProvider meet the requirement. (In your scenario, this check will fail).
So an easy working way is : 
In App.razor use <Routes /> instead of <Routes @rendemode="xxx"/> to make sure "Routes.razor" is in the SSR mode when you visit that page.
In Routes.razor use <RouteView RouteData=/> instead of <AuthorizedRouteView RouteData=.../> to skip the second check.
Then this App will work the same is WebAPI.

hmm still does not work for me. I changed <AuthorizedRouteView to <RouteView and added @rendermode InteractiveServer to component. Still throwing Error: 401 no redirect. I am using builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints().AddEntityFrameworkStores(); as auth scheme (for both cookie and bearer token) and I noticed its behaving wierd with this auth config e.g. also when I click logout in navmenu it logs me out but throws 401 standard page. So maybe thats the issue :/

@MarekHavrila if you just want a redirect,  then you shouldn't skip the second check.  Instead ,you could skip the first check, then you will be redirect using <RedirectToLogin /> component. But from my view, you can never pass this "bearer authorize" when using second check.

Ah okay I just realized it that 401 without redirect is because of <AuthorizedRouteView. Thank you. But why is <RouteView now working and still throws 401 for bearer token. Is there any other check for it? Is using @rendermode InteractiveServer correct?

@MarekHavrila No other checks. 1.with AuthorizedRouteView  httpcheck-> (when pass)-> stateprovider check (can be redirect by component).  2. with RouteView only httpcheck.    So either way, when you didn't pass the httpcheck.  you are blocked by httpway which is 401 for bearer.

Thank you for the patience! I understand better now, still dont know or where to check what is not passing but at least I have big picture now.
